# $_php['creds'] is empty while posting with ng2

Tags: php, rest, angular

`$_post['creds']` is empty for ng2 restful webservice:

```
let creds  = "email=" + userDetails.email + "&password=" + userDetails.password;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     this.http.post("http://www.dr-gontar.com/checkSignIn/", creds, options)
        .subscribe((data:Response) => this.id = JSON.parse(data.text()).id);

this.http.post("http://www.dr-gontar.com/checkSignIn/", creds, options )
    .subscribe((data:Response) => this.email = JSON.parse(data.text()).email);

this.http.post("http://www.dr-gontar.com/checkSignIn/", creds, options )
    .subscribe((data:Response) => this.name = JSON.parse(data.text()).name);

this.http.post("http://www.dr-gontar.com/checkSignIn/", creds, options)
    .subscribe((data:Response) => this.mobile = JSON.parse(data.text()).mobile);

this.http.post("http://www.dr-gontar.com/checkSignIn/", creds, options )
    .subscribe((data:Response) => this.address = JSON.parse(data.text()).address);

this.userDetails = [this.id,this.email,this.name,this.mobile,this.address];
console.log(this.userDetails);
```

Comment: This code is not complete, just a method that even doesn't do anything. Please edit and add full code sample if you want help ...

Comment: this.http.post("http://www.dr-gontar.com/checkSignIn/", creds, options)
        .subscribe((data:Response) => this.id = JSON.parse(data.text()).id);

Comment: I don't know for Angular2 but in Angular you read $_POST with `file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`URLSearchParams`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html):

```
sendUserAndPass(userDetails) {
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('email', userDetails.email);
  body.set('password', userDetails.password)

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.post('url', body.toString(), options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Then you can e.g get your e-mail like:

```
$_POST['email']
```

Comment: Please don't edit my answer to add additional information ;) So have you tried just to check that the values are received in the backend?

Comment: ...Meaning that you don't try and do anything with the values before checking that you actually have them there? :)

Comment: i am sorry, please undo the editting. there is a small progress but something strange. it fails to do Access-Control-Allow-Origin despite i php'ed it like that : header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); this is the error :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138336/discussion-between-ajt-82-and-daniel-gontar).